# C++ own shared ptr class

Tags: c++, c++20, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I tried to write my own shared_ptr class a simple one to get more grasp of it along with move & copy constructor and move & copy assignment operator. It looks something like below:-

```
// Online C++ compiler to run C++ program online
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
template<class T>
class my_shared_ptr
{
    private:
        T* ptr = nullptr;
        int* refcount = nullptr;
    
    public:
        my_shared_ptr() : ptr(nullptr),refcount(new int (0))
        {std::cout <<"Inside my_shared_ptr constructor \n" ;}
        
        my_shared_ptr(T* pT) : ptr(pT),refcount(new int (0))
        {std::cout <<"Inside my_shared_ptr with pT passed in constructor \n" ;}
        
        ~my_shared_ptr()
        {
            std::cout <<"Inside Destructor of my_shared_ptr \n";
            (*refcount)--;
            std::cout <<"Inside Destructor refcount is : "<< (*refcount) <<"\n";
            if((*refcount) == 0)
            {
                std::cout <<"Deleting the one of the ptr whose reference count is now 0 \n";
                delete ptr;
            }   
        }
        
        // Copy constructor 
        
        my_shared_ptr(const my_shared_ptr& obj)
        {
            std::cout <<"Inside copy constructor call \n";
            this->ptr = obj.ptr;
            this->refcount = obj.refcount;
            
            if(obj.ptr != nullptr)
            {
                (*this->refcount)++;
            }
        }
        
        // Copy assignment operator 
        my_shared_ptr& operator=(const my_shared_ptr& obj)
        {
            std::cout <<"Inside copy assignment call \n";
            if(&obj == this )
                return *this;
            
            (*this->refcount)--;
            if((*this->refcount) == 0)
            {
                delete (this->ptr);
            }
            this->ptr = obj.ptr;
            this->refcount = obj.refcount;
            
            if( obj.ptr!= nullptr)
            {
                (*this->refcount)++;
            }
            return *this;
        }
        
        // Move constructor 
        my_shared_ptr(my_shared_ptr&& dyingobj) 
        {
            std::cout <<"Inside move constructor call \n";
            this->ptr = dyingobj.ptr;
            this->refcount = dyingobj.refcount;
            dyingobj.ptr = nullptr; // cleaning up the dying object
            dyingobj.refcount = nullptr;
        }
        
        // Move assignment
        my_shared_ptr& operator=(my_shared_ptr&& dyingobj)
        {
            std::cout <<"Inside move assignment call \n";
            if(&dyingobj == this )
            {
                std::cout <<"Two objects in move assignment are equal \n";
                return *this;
            }
            if( (this) != &dyingobj )
            {
                (this->refcount)--;
                std::cout <<"Inside move assignment refcount is : "<< (*refcount) <<"\n";
                if((this->refcount) == 0)
                {
                    std::cout <<"Deleting the previous shared object pointer whose reference count is now 0 \n";
                    delete this->ptr;
                }
            }
        
            this->ptr = dyingobj.ptr;
            this->refcount = dyingobj.refcount;
            dyingobj.ptr = nullptr; // cleaning up the dying object
            dyingobj.refcount = nullptr;
            return *this;
        }
        
        T* operator->() const
        {
            return ptr;
        }
        
        T& operator*() const
        {
            return *ptr;
        }
        
};

class Resource
{
    public:
        Resource()
        {
            std::cout <<"Resource Acquired \n"; 
        }
        
        ~Resource()
        {
            std::cout <<"Resource Destroyed \n";
        }
};

my_shared_ptr<Resource> generateResource()
{
    my_shared_ptr<Resource> res(new Resource());
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout <<"Before Creating mainres \n";
    my_shared_ptr<Resource> mainres = generateResource();
    std::cout <<"After Creating mainres \n";
    mainres = generateResource();
    std::cout <<"Before Creating mainres2 \n";
    my_shared_ptr<Resource> mainres2 = mainres;
    std::cout <<"After Creating mainres2 \n";
    {
        std::cout <<"Before Creating mainres3\n";
        my_shared_ptr<Resource> mainres3;
        mainres3 = mainres2;
        std::cout <<"After mainres3 assignment\n";
    }
    std::cout <<"mainres3 destroyed\n";
    //mainres = generateResource();
    return 0;
}
```

The Output of above code is :

```
Before Creating mainres 
Resource Acquired 
Inside my_shared_ptr with pT passed in constructor 
After Creating mainres 
Resource Acquired 
Inside my_shared_ptr with pT passed in constructor 
Inside move assignment call 
Inside move assignment refcount is : 0
Inside Destructor of my_shared_ptr
```

Looking at the O/P it seems code executed fine till `mainres = generateResource();` but then after this it exited silently. And I did not get any further o/p. Not sure why ? What would be right way to correct this and where am i wrong. Inside move assignment call i am trying to delete reduce reference count of the my_shared_ptr object that is being assigned a different my_shared_ptr and check if the reference count is 0 then delete the ptr of that my_shared_ptr object. Am i missing something here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this any help: https://godbolt.org/z/v8oKoKxx9 ?

Comment: Print the addresses in destructor and you may notice a problem.

Comment: If you're going to embark on printing messages in the constructors and destructor of a class, just printing out simple messages are of very little help.  What is a lot more help is printing out the value of `this` along with the message.  Otherwise you don't know what is actually being constructed and destroyed.

Comment: Bit of irony ... you have a memory leak as well

Comment: Among other things, the assignment operator decrements the reference count even if `ptr` is null. This will send the reference count negative, and things spiral out of control.

Comment: By the way, you never `delete refcount;` , which is a memory leak per shared object. Moreover you should start with rule of 3 first, then optimize with rule of 5. That is donot rush to define move constructor+move assignment. As a beginning step, it is much simpler and safer to implement rule of 3 with **copy+swap idiom**; other approaches involve optimizations that are a bit too early right now.

Comment: Thanks everyone, so it seemed that i tried to move a temp object which got deleted and since the mainres acquired it resources from it, this deleted the mainres leading to the issue.

Comment: @Red.Wave Yeah idea is to use rule of 5 wherever we can, this was just to try a few things on my own. Yes i missed deleting the refcount, thanks for that.

Comment: I'm not sure what issue you noticed, but my comment was about the fact that you rely on fact that `refcount` is never `nullptr`, but then you null it both of your move operations. And then you try to access it in destructor to decrease it, but it's null.

Comment: `my_shared_ptr::my_shared_ptr(T* pT)` starts with reference count 0 instead of 1. If an object created using this constructor gets deleted you decrement the reference count to `-1`, i.e. the object won't be deleted in this case or will be deleted early, if you properly copy the smart pointer...

Comment: `(this->refcount)--;` Your move-assignment operator decrements the `refcount` pointer instead of _the object pointed to by it_.

Comment: @Invictus , I mean do everything, but step by step. That way you'll get a solid understanding. 1st apply rule of 3 with copy assignment and constructor ( do copy/swap). Then improve corner cases with careful implementation of move assignment and constructor. Do it, but patiently in stable steps.

Comment: @JesperJuhl how do you get to Carnegie Hall?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen yes thanks for this input , yes i modified the code to make sure that checks for nullptr etc. is done everywhere and it was helpful.

Comment: @fabian yes this was leading to incorrect reference number being printed when my last object was going out of scope setting this to 1 as it should be helped in getting rid of the issue. Thanks for it.

Comment: @Red.Wave Thanks for your input and encouragement

Comment: I wrote an article about smart pointers recently, I believe it might help you with the understanding of what happens behind the scenes: https://cppsenioreas.wordpress.com/2023/02/21/the-shared-the-unique-and-the-weak/
This article have two following articles about the initializations ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To learn about copy and move a class like the following is always very useful:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Verbose {
    Verbose() {
        std::cout << "   Verbose default construct\n";
    }

    Verbose(Verbose const&) {
        std::cout << "   Verbose copy construct\n";
    }

    Verbose(Verbose&&) {
        std::cout << "   Verbose move construct\n";
    }

    ~Verbose() {
        std::cout << "   Verbose destruct\n";
    }

    Verbose& operator=(Verbose const&) {
        std::cout << "   Verbose copy assign\n";
        return *this;
    }

    Verbose& operator=(Verbose&&) {
        std::cout << "   Verbose move assign\n";
        return *this;
    }
};
```

This allows you to track exactly what is being called in the output. Between the calls you should insert further output to be able to recognize from the output where within `main()` you are.

```cpp
int main() {
    std::cout << "Default construct a\n";
    auto a = Verbose();
    std::cout << "address of a is: " << &a << '\n';

    std::cout << "Copy construct b from a\n";
    auto b = a;
    std::cout << "address of a is: " << &a << '\n';
    std::cout << "address of b is: " << &b << '\n';

    std::cout << "Move construct c from a\n";
    auto c = std::move(a);
    std::cout << "address of a is: " << &a << '\n';
    std::cout << "address of b is: " << &b << '\n';
    std::cout << "address of c is: " << &c << '\n';
}
```

```
Default construct a
   Verbose default construct
address of a is: 0x7ffd1a93cdf5
Copy construct b from a
   Verbose copy construct
address of a is: 0x7ffd1a93cdf5
address of b is: 0x7ffd1a93cdf6
Move construct c from a
   Verbose move construct
address of a is: 0x7ffd1a93cdf5
address of b is: 0x7ffd1a93cdf6
address of c is: 0x7ffd1a93cdf7
   Verbose destruct
   Verbose destruct
   Verbose destruct
```

If this part is clear to you, then next you can use the class in a SmartPointer to understand it better:

```cpp
#include <memory>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Default construct shared a\n";
    auto a = std::make_shared<Verbose>();
    std::cout << "shared a points to: " << a.get() << '\n';

    std::cout << "Copy construct shared b from shared a\n";
    auto b = a;
    std::cout << "shared a points to: " << a.get() << '\n';
    std::cout << "shared b points to: " << b.get() << '\n';

    std::cout << "Move construct shared c from shared a\n";
    auto c = std::move(a);
    std::cout << "shared a points to: " << a.get() << '\n';
    std::cout << "shared b points to: " << b.get() << '\n';
    std::cout << "shared c points to: " << c.get() << '\n';
}
```

```
Default construct shared a
   Verbose default construct
shared a points to: 0x559a146ae2d0
Copy construct shared b from shared a
shared a points to: 0x559a146ae2d0
shared b points to: 0x559a146ae2d0
Move construct shared c from shared a
shared a points to: 0
shared b points to: 0x559a146ae2d0
shared c points to: 0x559a146ae2d0
   Verbose destruct
```

You can also give the `Verbose` class an ID to track the individual objects.

```cpp
struct Verbose {
    std::string id_ = "nameless";

    void rename(std::string id) {
        std::cout << "   Verbose rename from " << id_ << " to " << id << "\n";
        id_ = std::move(id);
    }

    Verbose() {
        std::cout << "   Verbose default construct " << id_ << "\n";
    }

    Verbose(Verbose const& o) {
        std::cout << "   Verbose copy construct " << id_ << "<=" << o.id_ << "\n";
    }

    Verbose(Verbose&& o) {
        std::cout << "   Verbose move construct " << id_ << "<=" << o.id_ << "\n";
    }

    ~Verbose() {
        std::cout << "   Verbose destruct " << id_ << "\n";
    }

    Verbose& operator=(Verbose const& o) {
        std::cout << "   Verbose copy assign " << id_ << "<=" << o.id_ << "\n";
        return *this;
    }

    Verbose& operator=(Verbose&& o) {
        std::cout << "   Verbose move assign " << id_ << "<=" << o.id_ << "\n";
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Note that the ID is only changed via the `rename()` function!

```cpp
int main() {
    std::cout << "Default construct of a\n";
    auto a = Verbose();
    a.rename("a");
    std::cout << "address of a is: " << &a << '\n';

    std::cout << "Copy construct b from a\n";
    auto b = a;
    b.rename("b");
    std::cout << "address of a is: " << &a << '\n';
    std::cout << "address of b is: " << &b << '\n';

    std::cout << "Move construct c from a\n";
    auto c = std::move(a);
    c.rename("c");
    std::cout << "address of a is: " << &a << '\n';
    std::cout << "address of b is: " << &b << '\n';
    std::cout << "address of c is: " << &c << '\n';
}
```

```
Default construct of a
   Verbose default construct nameless
   Verbose rename from nameless to a
address of a is: 0x7ffee311aba0
Copy construct b from a
   Verbose copy construct nameless<=a
   Verbose rename from nameless to b
address of a is: 0x7ffee311aba0
address of b is: 0x7ffee311abc0
Move construct c from a
   Verbose move construct nameless<=a
   Verbose rename from nameless to c
address of a is: 0x7ffee311aba0
address of b is: 0x7ffee311abc0
address of c is: 0x7ffee311abe0
   Verbose destruct c
   Verbose destruct b
   Verbose destruct a
```

This example also nicely shows the order of deconstructor calls. It is exactly the reverse of the construction order.

Here is another simplified `SharedPtr` implementation that also does extensive output:

```cpp
struct SharedState {
public:
    SharedState(Verbose* ptr): ptr_(ptr), count_(1) {
        std::cout << "  SharedState construct " << id() << "\n";
    }

    ~SharedState() {
        std::cout << "  SharedState destruct " << id() << "\n";
        delete ptr_;
    }

    SharedState(SharedState const& o) = delete;
    SharedState(SharedState&& o) = delete;
    SharedState& operator=(SharedState const& o) = delete;
    SharedState& operator=(SharedState&& o) = delete;

    std::size_t increase() {
        return ++count_;
    }

    std::size_t decrese() {
        return --count_;
    }

    Verbose* get() const {
        return ptr_;
    }

    std::string id() const {
        return ptr_->id_ + "$" + std::to_string(count_);
    }

private:
    Verbose* ptr_;
    std::size_t count_;
};

class SharedPtr {
public:
    std::string id() const {
        using namespace std::literals;
        return id_ + "->" + (state_ ? state_->id() : "nullptr"s);
    }

    void rename(std::string id) {
        std::cout << " SharedPtr rename from " << this->id_ << " to " << id << "\n";
        id_ = std::move(id);
    }

    SharedPtr(): state_(nullptr)  {
        std::cout << " SharedPtr default construct " << id() << "\n";
    }

    SharedPtr(Verbose* ptr): state_(new SharedState(ptr)) {
        std::cout << " SharedPtr direct construct " << id() << "\n";
    }

    SharedPtr(SharedPtr const& o) {
        std::cout << " SharedPtr copy construct " << id() << "<=" << o.id() << "\n";
        setSharedState(o.state_);
        std::cout << " ======================== " << id() << "<=" << o.id() << "\n";
    }

    SharedPtr(SharedPtr&& o) {
        std::cout << " SharedPtr move construct " << id() << "<=" << o.id() << "\n";
        setSharedState(o.state_);
        o.removeSharedState();
        std::cout << " ======================== " << id() << "<=" << o.id() << "\n";
    }

    ~SharedPtr() {
        std::cout << " SharedPtr destruct " << id() << "\n";
        removeSharedState();
    }

    SharedPtr& operator=(SharedPtr const& o) {
        std::cout << " SharedPtr copy assign " << id() << "<=" << o.id() << "\n";
        removeSharedState();
        setSharedState(o.state_);
        std::cout << " ===================== " << id() << "<=" << o.id() << "\n";
        return *this;
    }

    SharedPtr& operator=(SharedPtr&& o) {
        std::cout << " SharedPtr move assign " << id() << "<=" << o.id() << "\n";
        removeSharedState();
        setSharedState(o.state_);
        o.removeSharedState();
        std::cout << " ===================== " << id() << "<=" << o.id() << "\n";
        return *this;
    }

    Verbose* get() const {
        return state_ ? state_->get() : nullptr;
    }

    Verbose* operator->() const {
        if (!state_) {
            throw std::logic_error("dereference nullptr");
        }
        return state_->get();
    }

private:
    void removeSharedState() {
        if (state_) {
            if(state_->decrese() == 0) {
                delete state_;
            }
            state_ = nullptr;
        }
    }

    void setSharedState(SharedState* state) {
        state_ = state;
        if (state_) {
            state_->increase();
        }
    }

    std::string id_ = "Nameless";
    SharedState* state_ = nullptr;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Default construct A\n";
    auto A = SharedPtr(new Verbose);
    A->rename("a");
    A.rename("A");
    std::cout << A.id() << " points to: " << A.get() << '\n';

    std::cout << "Copy construct B from A\n";
    auto B = A;
    B.rename("B");
    std::cout << A.id() << " points to: " << A.get() << '\n';
    std::cout << B.id() << " points to: " << B.get() << '\n';

    std::cout << "Move construct C from A\n";
    auto C = std::move(A);
    C.rename("C");
    std::cout << A.id() << " points to: " << A.get() << '\n';
    std::cout << B.id() << " points to: " << B.get() << '\n';
    std::cout << C.id() << " points to: " << C.get() << '\n';
}
```

```
Default construct A
   Verbose default construct nameless
  SharedState construct nameless$1
 SharedPtr direct construct Nameless->nameless$1
   Verbose rename from nameless to a
 SharedPtr rename from Nameless to A
A->a$1 points to: 0x565113a0e2c0
Copy construct B from A
 SharedPtr copy construct Nameless->nullptr<=A->a$1
 ======================== Nameless->a$2<=A->a$2
 SharedPtr rename from Nameless to B
A->a$2 points to: 0x565113a0e2c0
B->a$2 points to: 0x565113a0e2c0
Move construct C from A
 SharedPtr move construct Nameless->nullptr<=A->a$2
 ======================== Nameless->a$2<=A->nullptr
 SharedPtr rename from Nameless to C
A->nullptr points to: 0
B->a$2 points to: 0x565113a0e2c0
C->a$2 points to: 0x565113a0e2c0
 SharedPtr destruct C->a$2
 SharedPtr destruct B->a$1
  SharedState destruct a$0
   Verbose destruct a
 SharedPtr destruct A->nullptr
```

If you want to use `SharedPtr` for arbitrary types, you have to make `SharedPtr` and `SharedState` templates. Note that this no longer assumes that the type `T` (previously `Verbose`) has an ID. Therefore it can no longer be displayed as part of the ID of `SharedPtr` and `SharedState`. This is the primary reason why I did not show a generic version right away.

The following diff shows the places you need to change. Lines that start with minus out. Lines that start with plus in. (Unfortunately StackOverflow currently has no syntax highlighting for this).

```
diff --git a/main.cpp b/main.cpp
index 2a511ea..b02f931 100644
--- a/main.cpp
+++ b/main.cpp
@@ -36,9 +36,10 @@ struct Verbose {
     }
 };
 
+template <typename T>
 struct SharedState {
 public:
-    SharedState(Verbose* ptr): ptr_(ptr), count_(1) {
+    SharedState(T* ptr): ptr_(ptr), count_(1) {
         std::cout << "  SharedState construct " << id() << "\n";
     }
 
@@ -60,19 +61,20 @@ public:
         return --count_;
     }
 
-    Verbose* get() const {
+    T* get() const {
         return ptr_;
     }
 
     std::string id() const {
-        return ptr_->id_ + "$" + std::to_string(count_);
+        return "ref_count$" + std::to_string(count_);
     }
 
 private:
-    Verbose* ptr_;
+    T* ptr_;
     std::size_t count_;
 };
 
+template <typename T>
 class SharedPtr {
 public:
     std::string id() const {
@@ -89,7 +91,7 @@ public:
         std::cout << " SharedPtr default construct " << id() << "\n";
     }
 
-    SharedPtr(Verbose* ptr): state_(new SharedState(ptr)) {
+    SharedPtr(T* ptr): state_(new SharedState<T>(ptr)) {
         std::cout << " SharedPtr direct construct " << id() << "\n";
     }
 
@@ -128,11 +130,11 @@ public:
         return *this;
     }
 
-    Verbose* get() const {
+    T* get() const {
         return state_ ? state_->get() : nullptr;
     }
 
-    Verbose* operator->() const {
+    T* operator->() const {
         if (!state_) {
             throw std::logic_error("dereference nullptr");
         }
@@ -149,7 +151,7 @@ private:
         }
     }
 
-    void setSharedState(SharedState* state) {
+    void setSharedState(SharedState<T>* state) {
         state_ = state;
         if (state_) {
             state_->increase();
@@ -157,12 +159,12 @@ private:
     }
 
     std::string id_ = "Nameless";
-    SharedState* state_ = nullptr;
+    SharedState<T>* state_ = nullptr;
 };
 
 int main() {
     std::cout << "Default construct A\n";
-    auto A = SharedPtr(new Verbose);
+    auto A = SharedPtr<Verbose>(new Verbose);
     A->rename("a");
     A.rename("A");
     std::cout << A.id() << " points to: " << A.get() << '\n';
```

I have not tested the assignment operators, please let me know if anything needs to be adjusted!

Comment: I think all inputs made sense, but effort you took to put it simply with all finer details made me to chose this as an answer. Thanks

Comment: I think it would have been better had the SharedState and SharedPtr used template <typename T> instead of Verbose . As it would have made it more generic for people to use this with any class rather than specific to Verbose.

Comment: @Invictus That was part of the simplification. You can just replace all the `Verbose` in `SharedState` and `SharedPtr` with `T` and make them both a template. But the output of the ID of `Verbose` as part IDs of `SharedPtr` and `SharedState` flies out! If there are any problems, just let me know ;-)

Comment: I tried doing that by declaring them as template< class T> and then replacing occurrence of Verbose in the both class with T. But i started getting the error : main.cpp:158:25: error: template placeholder type ‘SharedState<...auto...>’ must be followed by a simple declarator-id
  158 |     void setSharedState(SharedState* state) {
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:41:8: note: ‘template struct SharedState’ declared here
   41 | struct SharedState

Comment: @Invictus I added a Diff with the lines you need to change. Here is a live example with the generalized code: https://godbolt.org/z/bYahe3Wjq

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, i realized my knowledge of template syntax was causing a problem here. Just a quick question it looks like keeping a separate state class is more helpful specially when handling cases of move assignment, where you can delete state separately or set these to nulls, which seemed would have been difficult had these reference count be the part of shared pointer class itself. Right ?

Comment: Having all shared data in a `SharedState` class has the advantage that copy and move are easier to implement and the `SharedPtr` uses less memory (only one data member). The big disadvantage is that two pointer dereferences are necessary for each data access. Real implementations would probably only share the count, because the small advantage in memory size is less important than the very large disadvantage in access time. `sizeof(std::shared_ptr<int>)` is 16 for x64 libstdc++, which indicates that it holds one pointer to the object and one to the other data (count + deleter object).